# Vagrant VMware Desktop VM on Windows host - Folder Shares

Tags: vagrant, chmod, nfs, vmware-workstation, shared-directory

We switched from Vagrant on VirtualBox to Vagrant on VMware Desktop/Workstation Pro because of Enterprise Licensing. The hosts are Win10, the VM will be Linux.

All seems to work somehow, despite the folder sharing between host and VM. We tried many different ways, NFS, bindfs, smb, but none fit our needs.

It is required to allow at least `chmod` if not `chown` in the shared folder. The share will be websites hosted by nginx (Laravel Homestead VM). I had this working well on VirtualBox (however with a different/custom VM image), but not sure about the implementation on VMware.

Any idea how to properly implement folder sharing to allow `chmod` on a linux guest and Win host?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution (static though, `chmod` still not working) would be to mount the shares as `smb` with (at least) the following `mount_options`:

```
dir_mode=0755,file_mode=0660
```

Or however it fits the projects needs. (This hint I got from [Jeff Geerling](https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2016/developing-virtualbox-and-vagrant-on-windows)) But I am still interested if there is any way to enable `chmod` on shares from Win.